# Calculate the sum of group in a table and joining on other table sql

Tags: sql

i have two tables in sql.

table_team

```
t_id  team_name
 1      ABC
 2      XYZ
 3      PQR
```

i have another table_player

```
p_id t_id   player_name  payment
 10    1           Sam          1000
 20    1           jon           500
 30    2           will          680
 40    1           bob           700
 50    3           rob           890
```

i want to get the team's total payment from these two tables.

i'e sum of payemnt of each player in a particular team, and for all teams.

i thought of trying

```
select t_id,team_name,sum(b.payment) as total_payment from table_team a
left join table_player b on a.t_id = b.t_id
```

Comment: On your query, add group by and it will work ... group by t_id and team_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join to a subquery which computes the total payment for each team:

```
SELECT t1.t_id, t1.team_name, t2.total_payment
FROM table_team t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t_id, SUM(payment) AS total_payment
    FROM table_player
    GROUP BY t_id
) t2
    ON t1.t_id = t2.t_id
-- WHERE t1.team_name IN ('ABC', 'XYZ')
```

Comment: If i have to get results for only 2 teams, i'e ABC and XYZ, can i place `where team_name IN('ABC','XYZ')` before inner join ?

Comment: No, add `WHERE t1.team_name IN ('ABC', 'XYZ')` to the very end of the query.

Comment: Isn't better to go with sum() over (partition by ....) then having that nested select?

Comment: @Veljko89 The OP never specified a database.  Window functions would not be an option with MySQL, or SQLite, I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t_id,team_name,sum(b.payment) as total_payment 
from table_team a
left join table_player b on a.t_id = b.t_id
group by t_id,team_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t_id,team_name,sum(isnull(b.payment,0)) as total_payment from table_team a
left join table_player b on a.t_id = b.t_id
group by t_id, team_name
```

Just add a `group by` and it should work